# right working of ivy with archiva repository

Tags: maven, ant, ivy, archiva

I'm trying to understanding and using ivy with archiva, but i have this strange thing that i can't explain,

## Build.xml

```
...some xml code
<target name="resolveArchiva" description="--> go take the jar">
    <ivy:settings file="./archivaIvySetting.xml" >
        <credentials host="my host to Archiva" realm="my repository's name"
         username="user" passwd="passwd"/>
    </ ivy:settings>
    <ivy:retrieve />
 </target>
 some other code....
```

## Ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="archiva" module="my-repo"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="annogen" name="annogen" rev="0.1.0"/>
        <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.1" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

## arvchivaIvySetting.xml

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="archiva" />
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="archiva" m2compatible="true" root="repositories/internal/"/>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

the problem it's that in my repo there is an artifact for annogen but it's not present the common-lang artifact, despite that, the build says that it find the artifacts for both the dependencies, and that's true because i find both .jar in my lib project. How is it possible? it's clear that my setting doesn't point to the archiva rep but to the maven ones but how can i change it?

Comment: what's the exact realm? I believe it needs to be "Repository Archiva Managed internal Repository". Or perhaps you don't need the credentials and can give guest access if you're just looking to proxy public artifacts?

Comment: yes it was simply to write a generic folder, i'm using the Repository Archiva Managed internal Repository, but if i create a new repo i would have poot that name in the realm